# tornado vs wsgi(with gunicorn)

Tags: python, tornado, wsgi, uwsgi, gunicorn

I read [this](http://rz.scale-it.pl/2013/01/25/tornado___the_best_web_framework.html) about Tornado:

> On the other hand, if you already have a WSGI app and want to run it
>   on a blazing fast tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer, wraps it with
>   tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer.  But you need to be careful. Since your
>   original application is not prepared for an asynchronous server, and
>   will make a lot of IO/computation, it will block other requests while
>   generating a response (further requests will be accepted and buffered
>   but queued for later handling).

And Guincorn says:

> 'a Python WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX. It’s a pre-fork worker model
>   ported from Ruby’s Unicorn project.

1. So Gunicorn will spawn worker process to handle the request?
2. One concurent request per worker?
3. While tornado will use `epoll` or `kqueue` to do the work in one process(no master/worker process)?
4. So if I use blocking call(like `requests.get` in the handler's get/post function), This will block all the request handling or only the current request being handled?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you are running a WSGI application on top of Tornado, then there isn't a great deal of difference between Tornado and gunicorn in as much as nothing else can happen so long as the WSGI request is being handled by the application in a specific process. In the case of gunicorn because it only has one thread handling requests and in the case of Tornado because the main event loop will never get to run during that time to handle any concurrent requests.

In the case of Tornado there is actually also a hidden danger.

For gunicorn, because there is only one request thread, the worker process will only accept one web request at a time. If there are concurrent requests hitting the server, they will be handled by any other available worker processes instead as they all share the same listener socket.

With Tornado though, the async nature of the layer under the WSGI application means that more than one request could get accepted at the same time by one process. They will initially interleave as the request headers and content is read, which Tornado pre reads into memory before calling the WSGI application. When the whole request content has then been read, control will be handed off to the WSGI application to handle that one request. In the mean time, the concurrent request being handled by the same process for which the request headers and content hadn't yet been read, will be blocked for as long as the WSGI application takes to handle the first request.

Now if you only have the one Tornado process this isn't a big deal as the requests would be serialised anyway, but if you are using tornado worker mode of gunicorn so as to enable multiple Tornado worker processes sharing the same listener sockets this can be quite bad. This is because the greedy nature of individual processes resulting from the async layer, means requests can get blocked in a process when there could have been another worker process which could have handled it.

In summary, for a single Tornado web server process you are stuck with only being able to handle one request at a time. In gunicorn you can have multiple worker process to allow requests to be handle concurrently. Use a multi process setup with Tornado though and you risk having requests blocked.

So Tornado can be quite good for very small custom WSGI application where they don't do much and so response is very quick, but it can suffer where you have long running requests running under a blocking WSGI application. Gunicorn will therefore be better as it has proper ability to handle concurrent requests. With gunicorn being single threaded though and needing multiple worker processes though, it will use much more memory.

So they both have tradeoffs and in some cases you can be better off using a WSGI server that offers concurrency through multithreading as well as multiple worker processes. This allows you to handle concurrent requests, but not blow out memory usage through needing many worker processes. At the same time, you need to balance the number of threads per process with using multiple processes so as not to suffer unduly from the effects of the GIL in a CPU heavy application.

Choices for WSGI servers with multithreading abilities are mod_wsgi, uWSGI and waitress. For waitress though you are limited to a single worker process.

In all, which is the best WSGI server really depends a lot on the specifics of your web application. There is no one WSGI server which is the best at everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. So in case of C10K problem, the wsgi with gunicorn will be better. Could you give me more light about this: `This is because the greedy nature of individual processes resulting from the async layer, means requests can get blocked in a process when there could have been another worker process which could have handled it`,the different process share the same listen port, why can't another worker process to handle the incoming requests?

Comment: Because the first worker process has already accepted the socket connection and start reading data from it. Another process cannot take over the connection at that point. Is a similar issue to what was described for a WSGI module once written for embedding in nginx as described in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html

Comment: As to mythical C10K, sticking nginx on front of gunicorn with a WSGI application will not help much with that. The number of concurrent requests that gunicorn can handle is still limited by how many processes you can fit in memory, balanced against the fact that having many more worker processes than processor cores can in some cases be detrimental to performance because of how Python's GIL works in a multi processor system.

Comment: Fr the majority of sites C10k is actually not a practical benchmark or goal to try and achieve because you will never realistically ever have that, or if you do it is usually ridiculous to try and attain it on a single machine with your typical Python web application. If you have a specific requirement for a part of your application to maintain long running connections, then segment that out and write a special purpose async application for it. Don't infect the whole application with async just because one part needs it. Then have nginx route separately to WSGI and async applications.

Comment: Thanks, you did a nice job for this. We have C10K problem now. But as you stated, we should scale horizontally(and load balance the traffic).

Comment: The best thing about this answer are the comments putting the C10K problem in perspective. At least now I know both tornado and gunicorn shouldn't be used to handle that amount of traffic.

Comment: @Realistic - this is only true if you use WSGI inside tornado. As Graham Dumpleton explained: 'nothing else can happen so long as the WSGI request is being handled by the application in a specific process'. This is true for the WSGI interface. But if you use native tornado request handlers (e.g. no Gunicorn), then you are not limited to a single request. Then you can actually switch between requests using the await statement or by yielding Future instances from the request handler. You can also use Nginx to distribute requests between multiple tornado processes (instead of Gunicorn's master)