# Running Tornado service in Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, tornado

I'm porting an existing Tornado HTTP service to run on Kubernetes.

Should I add `gunicorn` or `uvicorn` inside the container before for Tornado processes?

Or should it be a just single Python process with Tornado inside the container?

Also, what are the benefits of using `gunicorn`/`uvicorn` for this?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: This answer proposes that there are benefits on running `gunicorn` with Tornado https://stackoverflow.com/a/22067306/7447711 . As of uvicorn, Tornado does not support ASGI natively, so it would be hacky to make it work.

Comment: Gunicorn is a server for WSGI apps (Django, Flask, et al). Tornado comes with a server of its own, therefore it doesn't need Gunicorn. Even Gunicorn docs don't recommend doing this:  https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#tornado-workers

Comment: @xyres I understood the docs exactly opposite. Although Tornado can be WSGI, it's not recommended. Hence one should use Gunicorn with Tornado worker

Comment: @Mikael thanks for the link! Strange I couldn't find this, I Googled and searched SO for this exact question